# Does multiple sizeMapping work?

Tags: google-dfp

I have configured mapping like this:

```
var mapping = googletag.sizeMapping().
    addSize([972, 0], [750, 100], [728, 90]).
    addSize([752, 0], [728, 90], [468, 60]).build();
```

I would expect for resolution greater than 972 DFP to choose 750x100 or 728x90 ad. To me it looks like it only considers the first size i.e. 750x100. Even though I have better paying and with higher priority creative of size 728x90. When I get to delivery diagnostics there's information about request and it says "Request sizes 750x100". I would expect to have there both sizes. Am I missing something or in fact those multiple sizes are not supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
addSize([972, 0], [[750, 100], [728, 90]]).
```

Wrap the sizes in an array.